# str to date mysql function default day

Tags: mysql

is it possible to default the day field when using the string to date function in MySQL ?

I am using this:

```
   sample_date = cast(STR_TO_DATE(@sampl_date,'%Y%m') AS date)
```

the input values I am receiving are in the format of

201305

201203

etc

so the str_to_date function works fine in converting that but it shows the day as 00 which I would like to default all of them to 01.

I tried various forms of the str_to_date function but none worked.

```
 sample_date = cast(STR_TO_DATE(@sampl_date,'%Y%m%01') AS date)

 sample_date = cast(STR_TO_DATE(@sampl_date,'%Y%m-01') AS date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
cast(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@sampl_date, '01'),'%Y%m%d') AS date)
```